# Error in deserialize the object array in javascript

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, deserialization

I am trying to post a  Object Array through Ajax and Jquery.

Every time I am getting the bellow error in javasript.

> Message: "Type 'System.String' is not supported for deserialization of
> an array.",…} ExceptionType: "System.InvalidOperationException"
> Message: "Type 'System.String' is not supported for deserialization of
> an array."

```js
var jsonPayloadItemDetails = [{
  "ConnoteID": connoteID1,
  "ItemCategory": itemCategory1,
  "ItemWeight": itemWeight1,
  "itemLength": itemLength1
}, {
  "ConnoteID": connoteID2,
  "ItemCategory": itemCategory2,
  "ItemWeight": itemWeight2,
  "itemLength": itemLength2
}];

if (jsonPayloadItemDetails != "") {
  $.ajax({
    url: window.location.href.replace(window.location.search, '').replace(window.location.hash, '') + '/MyMethodToHandleAjaxRequest',
    data: JSON.stringify({
      ItemDetails: jsonPayloadItemDetails
    }),
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function(result) {
      var message = "";
      if (result) {
      } else {
        message = "An error occurred"
      }
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      console.log(errorThrown);
    }
  });
}
```

In C#, I am trying to get the value as

```
public static bool MyMethodToHandleAjaxRequest(string ItemDetails)
{
  var currentLineItems =   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(ItemDetails);
}
```

I understand that `JSON.stringify()` could not deserialize the object array.
What is the best option  I can use here?
Thanks.

Comment: "*I understand that JSON.stringify() could not deserialize the object array.*" are you sure? To me it seems like completely the opposite problem - it's the backend which is unable to process things. In fact, I think it complains because you've declared `ItemDetails` as `string` but *it is not* a string. It's a properly serialised object and therefore the server will try to automatically deserialise it and assign it to a string but that's not possible. You should probably make it `JObject` or better yet, create an actual type for it.

Comment: `I understand that JSON.stringify() could not deserialize the object array`...what makes you say that? The error is clearly coming from your C# code, as VLAZ says